# Passing a readonly variable to parent constructor | Typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, super

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to pass a `readonly` variable to the constructor of a parent class:

```
abstract class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private readonly READ_ONLY: number= 1;

    public constructor(foo: string)
        // 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class. ts(17009)
        super(foo, this.READ_ONLY); 
    }
}
```

ChildClass will be extended by more classes, therefore the abstract.

Is there any way I can pass the read-only variable in the `super` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `readonly`.

You *cannot* reference any property of `this` before the superclass's constructor is called. So you have to do this in a different way.

Perhaps `READ_ONLY` is a protected property of `ParentClass`, and then child classes can set a new value for it.

```
class ParentClass {
  protected readonly READ_ONLY: number = 1;
  constructor(foo: string) {
    console.log('used READ_ONLY: ', this.READ_ONLY)
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  protected readonly READ_ONLY: number = 2;
}

new ParentClass('foo') // used READ_ONLY: 1
new ChildClass('foo') // used READ_ONLY: 2
```

This works because `protected` just means `private` to the outside, but `public` to subclasses.

Comment: READ_ONLY is a value that changes from subclass to subclass. For example, a sibling class ChildClass2 would pass the value 2, but the parent class should not have a default READ_ONLY value, it should be given by a child class.